# Is it possible to see tcpdump real source code?

Tags: apt, source-code, tcpdump

Before question, my question article may have some incorrect content. I am a linux newbie and a newbie developer.

I have a question regarding linux **tcpdump** source code. As I know tcpdump is implemented using **libpcap.**

1. How tcpdump is work? My opinion is that since tcpdump binary executable file is set in **PATH.** right?
2. My main question is that where is tcpdump c source code? I already knew tcpdump library code which is accessible tcpdump homepage [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

> I want to see tcpdump real c code containing main function, variable header files. Please let me know the location.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: You can find the source here (https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump). From the developper's site, you can clone the tcpdump GitHub repository using:

`git clone https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump.git`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tcpdump` is available in the `main` repository in Ubuntu.

To download the source code of `tcpdump`:

- Make sure you have the repositories enabled for `deb-src` type packages, for `xenial` (16.04) add the following to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
  ```

  Replace `xenial` with your release codename, you can find your release codename by:

  ```
  lsb_release -sc
  ```
- Now update the local package list by synchronizing with the repositories:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install the source code of `tcpdump`:

  ```
  apt-get source tcpdump
  ```

  It will be downloaded and auto-extracted on the current directory; also no need for `sudo` unless you don't have write permission on the directory.

All the files you need are inside the directory `tcdump-<version>` e.g. for version `4.5.1` the directory would be `tcpdump-4.5.1`.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. In tcpdump-4.7.4 directory, what is the c code file name containing main function

Comment: @박주현 Check `tcpdump.c`

Comment: thank you. I want to be sure one more time.
when we type <pre> **tcpdump icmp** <code> in terminal, then tcpdump.c source file is run? right?

Comment: oh sorry. typo. <pre> <code> is typo. sorry

Comment: @박주현 The compiled binary would be run then, the binary is compiled from the source so yes, same thing..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand well your first question, but:

1. You can find the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump). As indicated on the developer's site, you can clone the `tcpdump` GitHub repository using:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump.git
   ```
2. When you compile the code, you will have to decide where you want your executable to reside. Just make sure that it is located somewhere your user `PATH` variable points to or just modify your `PATH` to include that location.

You can also install it directly from Canonical repo through `sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE` or `sudo apt-get install DEB_PACKAGE` or using a GUI if you fancy one... In that case you'll find your binary at `/usr/sbin/tcpdump`. In addition

```
 whereis tcpdump
```

will give you the location of your binary (above), your source code and your man page files.

Comment: @박주현: my pleasure. heemayl beat me with a better answer. You should mark his as the going answer.

Comment: Do you intentionally always type 'yr' instead of 'your'?